# Cannot dump MongoDB Atlas database. Get "dumping up to 0 collections in parallel"

Tags: database, mongodb, backup, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

I am trying to make a dump of my MongoDB Atlas database using the command given under the database cmd line tools, under binary import and export tools. Here's a picture of where the command was taken from in Atlas:

[image]

I'm modifying the actual command a bit, here it is: mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://admin@.5x1p3.mongodb.net/ -vvvv

The command seems to run and I get no error messages but it does not actually provide me with a dump of the database. I get the following message upon running the command in windows cmd:

[image: Output after running the command]

It doesn't provide me with any information as to what could be going wrong. I tried disconnectiing my application from the databse before running the command but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a collection and a database are not the same thing. The correct command is:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<your_server_url>/<db_name> --collection <collection_name> -o . -v
```

[image]